# Random color for each child element

Tags: jquery, random, colors

I'm trying to write a function which will set a random text color to any element with 'randomcolor' class. So I have this

```
$('.randomcolor').each( function() {
    $(this).css('color', randomColor());
}
```

..but it doesn't seem to work, even though it doesn't make any errors.

`randomColor()` function works pretty well (or not?), I've already tested it:

`function randomColor() { return '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16); }`

So what's the problem with my code?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem with fiddle??

Comment: Post more code, and the `randomColor` function!

Comment: seems fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vns2ts1m/1/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, here http://jsfiddle.net/ggxarb4u/

Comment: does the randomcolor method returns a color value

Comment: where is the randomColor method

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vns2ts1m/2/ - missing `)` at the end of `$('.randomcolor').each( function() {
    $(this).css('color', randomColor());
})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Thank you, it works fine (somehow, my function worked or not randomly, every time for random elements ,_,)

Comment: Your algorithm is bad.  It has the chance to produce a color value of #12345 or #1234 (must be 6 characters long to be valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate random color using following method

```js
$('.randomcolor').each(function() {
  $(this).css('color', "#" + (Math.random() * 16777215 | 0).toString(16))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="randomcolor">abc</div>
<div class="randomcolor">abc</div>
<div class="randomcolor">abc</div>
<div class="randomcolor">abc</div>
<div class="randomcolor">abc</div>
<div class="randomcolor">abc</div>
<div class="randomcolor">abc</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it that function that can give incorrect color values sometimes? Or it's fixed by putting a zero after magic number?

Comment: @Endym : it's to avoid the fractional part